# Наполнение Android-приложения данными.SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Уважаемые гуру, помогите определиться с выбором.

База приложения должна содержит порядка 500 записей. Какой способ наполнения лучше выбрать?

1) сохранить структуру базы и ее данные в виде SQL скриптов, включить эти скрипты в приложение

2) передать базу данных в составе приложения в виде файла SQLite базы.

Comment: да как хош так и делай. слишком обширный вопрос

Answer (score 8):

Лучше всего заранее подготовить БД в стороннем desktop приложении (например [SLQite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)) и кинуть его в `assets` и оттуда уже при первом запуске приложения скопировать через:

```
context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Иначе, создание БД из скриптов и вставка 500 записей при первом запуске приложения занятие не самое веселое.

Comment: Круто, не успел написать ответ ))))

Answer (score 5):

Я решал так,

1. Создал базу локально на PC с помощью SQLiteBrowser
2. Сохранил файл базы (бинарный файл) в assets
3. Потом при первом запуске скопировал базу на телефон

   ```
   public void initialise() {
       if (mInstance == null) {
           if (!checkDatabase()) {
               copyDataBase();
           }
           mInstance = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(mContext, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
           mSqliteDb = mInstance.getWritableDatabase();
       }
   }
   ```

и как скопировал

```
private static void copyDataBase() {

    try {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

        // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
        File f = new File(mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```