# Как скопировать данные из бд

Tags: sqlite, android

У меня есть две базы данных: `first_base` и `second_base`. Как скопировать данные из первой базы во вторую (таблицы такие же)? Все базы лежат локально и все таблицы одинаковые. Просто одна база заполнена, а другая - нет.

Comment: файлы локально или у клиента?

Comment: если верно понял то поля в таблицах одинаковы, то почему не sql-запросом?

Comment: @ivanK. тут у него базы разные. Один запрос не сможет с 2я базами работать

Comment: @Saidolim. Проморгал что базы разные_) ну тогда через какую, то переменную в которой будут хранится данные. Первый sql на получение, затем sql на insert. Вот и всё.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359205/copying-data-from-one-sqlite-db-to-another

Comment: @Saidolim, локально. И я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @ivanK, неужели никак нельзя, кроме тупого копирования?

Comment: Вон Вам выше ссылку на ответ скинули.

Comment: @ivanK., я ничего там не понял, если честно.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как в андроиде, но классический вариант с `sqlite`:

```
attach database 'company1.db' as c1;
attach database 'company2.db' as c2;
insert into c2.table ... select * from c1.table;
```

Answer (score 0):

если файлы локально и их просто нужно перекопировать, используйте [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Я так делал когда нужно было в приложении готовую базу сохранять.

С этой программой создавал файл с базой, заливал файл в `assets` и при первом использовании, копировал файл в папку БД телефона.

Comment: Я не могу получить доступ к копированию через сторонее приложение без root'a.

Comment: Значит базы у телефоне клиента. Я думал локально, а вас.

Comment: Я думал "у клиента" — это на другом компьютере...

Comment: Можете поподробнее о том, как Вы копировали? И что такое assets?

Comment: Это я отвечал тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431230/182317

Comment: Но все равно не понял, что такое assets. Это часть, которая идет с БД или что?

Comment: @bukashka101 assets это папка внутри проекта. В Android Studio папка должна быть в исходниках `src/main/assets/` из http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide