# Распаковка бд Android

Tags: android, база-данных, мобильная-разработка

Есть БД, я ее положил в архив, а архив в папку `assest`, как мне сделать так, чтобы при первом запуске архив переместился в рабочую папку телефона и распаковался там, чтобы к БД можно было обращаться оттуда?

Comment: Что именно из озвученных вопросов у вас затруднения вызывает?

Comment: Распаковка, да и вообще хотелось бы увидеть пример правильного кода, для реализации этого, не хочется потом переписывать, если что-то не совсем верно сделаю.

Answer (score 1):

тут у вас 2 вопроса в одном,

для разархивирование файла нашел следующее:

```
import android.util.Log; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry; 
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream; 

/** 
 * 
 * @author jon 
 */ 
public class Decompress { 
  private String _zipFile; 
  private String _location; 

  public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
    _location = location; 

    _dirChecker(""); 
  } 

  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

        if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
          _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
        } else { 
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
          for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
            fout.write(c); 
          } 

          zin.closeEntry(); 
          fout.close(); 
        } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  } 

  private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
    File f = new File(_location + dir); 

    if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
      f.mkdirs(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

[ссылка на статью](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

теперь как скопировать БД в память телефона. На этот вопрос я [отвечал ранее ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431230/182317)

```
private static void copyDataBase() {

    try {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

        // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
        File f = new File(mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

еще ссылки по теме
1. [BlenderViking/extract-archive-android-lib](https://github.com/BlenderViking/extract-archive-android-lib)
2. [How to speed up unzipping time in Java / Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4504291/4953620)